# Unable to call storyboard from xib

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

I am new to iOS development. I am trying to connect to a storyboard from xib file. My xib View Controller has a "Login" which if successful should connect to storyboard. I have googled and searched on stackoverflow for a solution and I am using this code that is given everywhere:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    YourViewController * yourView = (YourViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier ID"];
```

I have created an identifier for my storyboard as well. However, I am not being redirected to the storyboard no matter what I try. When the login finishes, I go back to my main View Controller (xib). I should be instead redirected to the storyboard. Here is what my code looks like in a file called ProfileTabView.m:

```
-(void) loginViewDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    ProfileTabView * yourView = (ProfileTabView *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myID"];

}
```

I have implemeted this code in the function that gets called once the login is successful. However, the storyboard "Storyboard" never gets called. Am i doing this right? Am I supposed to be writing this code anywhere else?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: You need to add "yourView".view to the view hierarchy by either push/present/add Subview. Where is that part of code in loginViewDidFinish?

Answer (score 3):

One more step:  present the new view controller...

```
-(void) loginViewDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    ProfileTabView * yourView = (ProfileTabView *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myID"];

    // it might be better to rename 'ProfileTabView' as 'ProfileTabViewController'
    // and 'yourView' as 'profileTabVC', by convention.  Anyway ...

    [self.presentViewController:yourView animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

If your login VC is in a navigation controller, then you would push the new vc:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) loginViewDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerID") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```